# laravel 5.5 Multi auth error 'InvalidArgumentException Authentication user provider [] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The error is

> InvalidArgumentException
>   …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\CreatesUserProviders.php42

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'adminss',
        ],
    ],
```

**Here's my provider array**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
            'drivers' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],

],
```

**This is my Admin model**

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $table = 'admins';


}
```

This worked in laravel 5.4 but I'm getting error in 5.5

Comment: Is it because of the extra s in  `adminss` ?

Comment: Fixed the typo. Still getting the same error